# change the option of all other select menus in page with same id

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and need help to figure this one.

I have three menus where you select and option and for each menu you select it displays a row of data. In each row (i.e. 3 row for 3 selections) another select menu is available for you to pick a provider for that product. I created another select that you select a default provider and onchange the other menus in the rows change. The problem I have is that they all have the same id because when you pick an option a function gets called. I tried to loop through all select and from those selects with id=x change selected option but only works for 1st select found with that id

```
echo" function pickprovider($name, $idname){ \n";

echo" <select name='$name' id='idname'> \n";
echo" <option>1stprovider </option> \n";
echo"  <option>2ndprovider </option>\n";
echo " </select>\n";
echo" }\n";

echo" function defaultprovider($name, $idname) {\n";
echo" <select name='$name' id='idname' onchange='changeDflt(this);'> \n";
echo " <option>1stprovider </option> \n";
echo " <option>2ndprovider </option> \n";
echo "</select>\n";
echo" }\n";

 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
 echo "function ChangeDflt(list) { \n";
 echo "var x = list.options[list.selectedIndex].text;\n";
 echo "var allSelects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');\n";
 echo "for (var i = 0; i < allSelects.length; i++) { \n";
 ....
 change selected options for selects 
 echo "}\n";
 echo "}\n";
 echo "</script<\n";
```

I do not know how to change the function to make a unique id everytime the function is called. ....Can I use "div" tag when I get all the select elements in page?

Comment: Your javascript makes no sense.  You can't just arbitrarily put HTML in a javascript function.  And, it's illegal to have more than one element with the same ID in a page.  You need to fix the design.

Comment: why does your javascript has HTML inside it ? This will never work !!

Comment: I actually have  echo "<tag name>\n;" the document is php

Comment: Why can't you change the function? Do you not have any control over the source?

Comment: sorry for the confussion...I can change the function. But, I do not know how to make the name or id unique everytime the function gets called. I was thinking it was easier to loop through all selects and surround it with a div for say and put a unique id there...instead of messing with the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish with the `select` elements but if you structure your PHP to emit HTML and JavaScript differently, it gets both easier to read and easier to write both your HTML and your JavaScript.

```
<?php
    $base_id = "mySelect";      // set the string used as the basis for ids
    $base_name = $base_id;      // set the string used as the basis for names. There's no reason it cannot be the same as the id.

    $select_id = $base_id;      // set a variable to use for the id of the select
    $select_name = $base_name;  // set a variable to use for the name of the select

    // start a loop to emit the select elements
    for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
        $select_id = $base_id.$i;       // set the id of the select to the base concatentated with the incrementer variable
        $select_name = $base_name.$i;   // same for the name. Variable value will be substituted on emission.
        echo "
<select name=\"$select_name\" id=\"$select_id\" onchange=\"changeDefault(this);\">
    <option value=\"0\">1st provider</option>
    <option value=\"1\">2nd provider</option>
</select>
";
    }
    // emit the JavaScript
    echo "
<script type='text/javascript'>
var changeDefault = function changeDefault(list) {
    var val = list.options[list.selectedIndex].value,           // get the value of the selected option
        allSelects = document.getElementsByTagName('select'),   // get the rest of the selects
        options = null,                                         // placeholder for option elements
        i = 0,                                                  // incrementer 1
        j = 0;                                                  // incrementer 2
    // change selected options for selects
    for (i = 0; i < allSelects.length; i += 1) {
        // get all option elements that are children of the select element
        options = allSelects[i].getElementsByTagName('option');
        // loop through the option elements
        for (j = 0; j < options.length; j += 1) {
            // set selected to true if the values match and false if they do not
            options[j].selected = options[j].value === val;
        }
    }
};
</script>
    ";
?>
```

That said, syntactical constructs like:

```
function defaultprovider($name, $idname) {
<select name='$name' id='idname' onchange='changeDflt(this);'>
 <option>1stprovider </option>
 <option>2ndprovider </option>
</select>
}
```

are completely invalid JavaScript code and will not run. You may want to review a tutorial on JavaScript. I recommend this one: http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Essential_Javascript_--_A_Javascript_Tutorial. It starts with the basics and explains JavaScript far better than I can.

Comment: Awesome example!! it worked. I selected a provider and it changed the default provider to all the other select menus. Also, thank you for the tutorial